# Why does the default pylintrc have so many disabled messages?

Tags: python, pylint, pylintrc

If you run `pylint --generate-rcfile > pylintrc` and look at the default rc file you'll see the following list of disabled warnings.

Why are they disabled by default?

```
disable=print-statement,
        parameter-unpacking,
        unpacking-in-except,
        old-raise-syntax,
        backtick,
        long-suffix,
        old-ne-operator,
        old-octal-literal,
        import-star-module-level,
        non-ascii-bytes-literal,
        raw-checker-failed,
        bad-inline-option,
        locally-disabled,
        locally-enabled,
        file-ignored,
        suppressed-message,
        useless-suppression,
        deprecated-pragma,
        apply-builtin,
        basestring-builtin,
        buffer-builtin,
        cmp-builtin,
        coerce-builtin,
        execfile-builtin,
        file-builtin,
        long-builtin,
        raw_input-builtin,
        reduce-builtin,
        standarderror-builtin,
        unicode-builtin,
        xrange-builtin,
        coerce-method,
        delslice-method,
        getslice-method,
        setslice-method,
        no-absolute-import,
        old-division,
           dict-iter-method,
        dict-view-method,
        next-method-called,
        metaclass-assignment,
        indexing-exception,
        raising-string,
        reload-builtin,
        oct-method,
        hex-method,
        nonzero-method,
        cmp-method,
        input-builtin,
        round-builtin,
        intern-builtin,
        unichr-builtin,
        map-builtin-not-iterating,
        zip-builtin-not-iterating,
        range-builtin-not-iterating,
        filter-builtin-not-iterating,
        using-cmp-argument,
        eq-without-hash,
        div-method,
        idiv-method,
        rdiv-method,
        exception-message-attribute,
        invalid-str-codec,
        sys-max-int,
        bad-python3-import,
        deprecated-string-function,
        deprecated-str-translate-call,
        deprecated-itertools-function,
        deprecated-types-field,
        next-method-defined,
        dict-items-not-iterating,
        dict-keys-not-iterating,
        dict-values-not-iterating
```

Comment: I suspect that's a list of *all* warnings that can be disabled, so that you can simply delete or comment out the ones you don't want to disable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the documentation's Frequently Asked Questions...](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#why-are-there-a-bunch-of-messages-disabled-by-default)

> Why are there a bunch of messages disabled by default?
>
> pylint does have some messages disabled by default, either because
>   they are prone to false positives or that they are opinionated enough
>   for not being included as default messages. But most of the disabled
>   messages are from the Python 3 porting checker, which is disabled by
>   default. It needs special activation with the --py3k flag.

Answer (score 2):

I think that such default rc file is designed to apply pylint to python2 code without tons of errors and warnings. Note: most of the disabled statements belongs to python2 syntax and standard library api:

- print-statement - `print` was a statement in Python2, in Python3 it is a function
- old-raise-syntax - there was `except Exception, e` syntax that is invalid for Python3, in Python3 `except Exception as e` is only valid
- xrange-builtin - `xrange` was replaced with `range`
- etc.

So, with this default rc you can use pylint for python2 code to find out such things as `redefined-outer-name`, `line-too-long` and other bad things without getting annoying errors and warnings for valid Python2 syntax and standard library calls.